# How to match only some characters with a regex?

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to check if a string matches only some characters with a regex.

For example, I would like to match only `a`, `b`, or `c`.

So, "aaacb" would pass, but "aaauccb" would not (because of the `u`).

I have tried this way:

```
/[a|b|c]+/
```

but it does not work, because the failing example passes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to make sure that your string consists **only** of those characters by anchoring the regex to the beginning and end of the string:

```
/^[abc]+$/
```

You also mixed up two concepts. Alternation (which would be `(a|b|c)`) and character classes (which would be `[abc]`). They are in this case equivalent. Your version would also allow `|` as a character.

Answer (score 0):

```
 /[^abc]/
```

Is a litterally copied example from [rubular](http://www.rubular.com). It matches any single character except: a, b, or c

Comment: Yup that makes things a bit simpler. But note that the result needs to be inverted for the required check, and the check for non-empty strings has to be done separately now.

Comment: This differs from the stated behavior in the empty string edge case.

Answer (score -1):

Try [abc]+

It will match a, b or c.

Comment: ...but still allow strings that contain other characters